# Data from database is not passed to the view.blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, controller

I am pretty new to Laravel, and I am facing an issue.
I creating a website where users can upload products (modules) to the site and for their product they have to choose a category aswell as subcategory.
Now, I want to create a view.blade which automatically displays all the uploaded products with their corresponding subcategory. So on the roof page I want to display all the uploaded modules with subcategory roof.

However, the view page is loaded but no data is displayed...

I have created a ModulesController:

```
{ class ModulesController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function create()
{
    return view('modules/create');
}


public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
        'description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'price' => ['required', 'string'],
        'category' => ['required', 'string'],
        'subcategory' => ['required', 'string'],
        'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);
    #dd($data);
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
    $image->save();

    auth()->user()->modules()->create([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'price' => $data['price'],
        'category' => $data['category'],
        'subcategory' => $data['subcategory'],
        'image' => $imagePath,

    ]);


    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
}
public function show(\App\Models\Module $module)
{
    return view('modules.show', compact('module'));
```

A corresponding model:

```
   class Module extends Model
{
   protected $fillable =[
    'title',
    'description',
    'price',
    'category',
    'subcategory',
    'image',
];

public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

}

A Module migration database:

```
  class CreateModulesTable extends Migration
 {

   public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->string('category');
        $table->string('subcategory');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->index('user_id');
    });
}
```

And I am trying to pass it to this view where I want to show all the images.
I have tried to use this loop but I can't make it work....

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex justify-center pt-8 sm:justify-start 
sm:pt-0">
            <h1>All modules with corresponding subcategory</h1>
            @if ( $module["subcategory"] == "dak" )
                @foreach ($modules as $module)
                    <a href="/module/{{ $module->id }}">
                        <img src="/storage/{{$module->image}}" 
class="w-100" alt=""/>
                    <a/>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

If anyone can help this would be much appreciated.

P.S. "dak" is a subcategory and means "roof".

Comment: What exactly is "not working?" what is the output you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: `@foreach` requires some more parameters, like `@foreach ($modules as $module)`. More on [Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops)

Comment: Independent of what you are trying to achieve:
you need to indicate an array/collection through which you want to iterate: `@foreach($collection as $element)`.
@brombeer was faster than me ;-)

Comment: @brombeer I can't believe i've missed that one.

Comment: @GertB. , the output I expect is all uploaded products that have the corresponding subcategory from the module database. The output I recieve is "undefined array key 1"

Comment: @bots the error is because you have no parameters in your `@foreach`, as commented by brombeer. In your Controller you only get one module...

Comment: @GertB. ,  I did  but now I am recieving the following: syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "("

Comment: So by removing the curly bracets in the If statement I was able to solve the syntax error. However, still no data is being passed to the view, does anyone have an idea?